# How to send Array of objects using Reactive Form in Angular without control iteration?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

Actually I'm getting an employee list from API and have to post the data as an **array of objects at one click**. The post data will look like this.

```
    {
"date" : "15/08/2020",  //Current Date
"empAttendance" : [
        {
                "EmpId":"3",
                "AttendanceType": "P"
        },
        {
                "EmpId":"5",
                "AttendanceType": "P"
        }, // More Like this.
        ]
}
```

The frontend looks like this-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sC61.png)

So, How to get through this? **Could you please help me.** I'm searching all over the internet. I'm new to angular. If there is any other idea that also is helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Exmpale](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwwumn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You may do it this way:
Component code:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export interface Attendence {
  date: String; //Current Date
  empAttendance: Array<Employee>;
}

export interface Employee {
  EmpId: String;
  AttendanceType: String;
}


@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  postArray: Attendence[];
  source = {
    date: "15/08/2020", //Current Date
    empAttendance: [
      {
        EmpId: "3",
        AttendanceType: "P"
      },
      {
        EmpId: "5",
        AttendanceType: "P"
      } // More Like this.
    ]
  };

  postData(source: any) {
     this.postArray = [
       {
         date:this.source.date,
        empAttendance:this.source.empAttendance
       }
     ]
     console.log(this.postArray);
    // below code should be in service.
    this.httpClient.post("url", this.postArray).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("Posted");
      },
      err => {
       // console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<button (click)="postData(source)" >Post Data</button>
```